# Restoring part of firestore export

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am following up documentation in:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/import

And I am trying to restore a collection `pets` in a backup from today. However I am getting this:

```
# gcloud firestore import gs://pets-backup/2021-02-26T02:27:05_54372/ --collection-ids='pets'
ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.import) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The requested kinds/namespaces are not available
```

I can confirm the `gs-bucket` exists and the collection `pets` too.

The error is not very helpful, I am not sure what I am dealing with.

I noticed within the export, there are folders `/all_namespaces/all_kinds`. When I try to import from these directly, I am getting:

```
gcloud firestore import 'gs://pets-backup/2021-02-26T02:27:05_54372/all_namespaces/all_kinds' --collection-ids='pets'
ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.import) NOT_FOUND: Google Cloud Storage file does not exist: /pets-backup/2021-02-26T02:27:05_54372/all_namespaces/all_kinds/all_kinds.overall_export_metadata
```

I can see there is only a file `all_namespaces_all_kinds.export_metadata` which doesn't match the file the import tool is looking for.

Comment: Is the export you are trying to extract this collection from an export of all the collections? As you can see in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#import_specific_collections), this is not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. This is really impractical :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by you in the comments, you are trying to extract a collection from and export of all the collections. Unfortunatelly this is currently not possible, as you can see in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#import_specific_collections):

> Only an export of specific collection groups supports an import of specific collection groups. You cannot import specific collections from an export of all documents.

If you'd like this to be changed, you can submit a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0) so that they can consider this functionality to be implemented.